# My Angular Universal SPA consumes to much memory. How to identify where memory is leaking?

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, garbage-collection, angular-universal

I have created a SPA:  http://vuzopoisk.ru using Angular 7 Universal. The program is deployed into Docker container. The problem is that memory usage of the application is constantly growing and after 12 hours it uses all available memory and gets stuck

After searching for possible solutions, found that lazy modules loading and async pipe can help. Implemented it but all in vain

How can I identify why Garbage Collector doesn't release memory and it keeps growing in my Angular SPA?

Comment: Are you saying that the memory usage on the Docker container is constantly growing, or on the browser?

Comment: On docker container but I believe it reflects memory consumption of all users